# Moving Jquery Project Into Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I recently completed a course in Lynda.com by Chris Converse that walks through how to create an [interactive map using Jquery](http://www.lynda.com/jQuery-1-5-tutorials/Create-an-Interactive-Map-with-jQuery/87636-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:interactive%20map%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2). Once finished I am left with the following files:

- index.html
- interactive_map.css
- interactive_map.js
- jquery-1.5.min

and images

Now I want to take this project and put it into a CMS page in my magento site.
After doing a bit of research, I've gleaned the following:

1. Go to /js and add a new folder called jquery, and place jquery-1.5.min in there
2. Open this file and add the following line of code to the end:`var   $j=jQuery.noConflict();`
3. Go to interactive_map.js and replace all the $ with $j
4. Go to my page.xml file under app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/page.xml
5. Add this line of code:

   ```
    <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.5.noConflict.min.js</script></action>
   ```

Additionally add this line of code:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/interactive_map.js</name></action>
```

6. Copy the information in interactive_map.css to skin/frontend/default/mytheme/css/styles.css. Change the css image links for the map and dots to mytheme/images
7. Go to skin/frontend/default/mytheme/js and add the my_interactivemap.js file
8. Move all the images to skin/frontend/default/mytheme/images
9. Create a CMS page, and in the content field, paste the code from the index.html file
10. In the CMS page, go to design, and in the Update Layout XML field add:

    ```
      <reference name="head">
             <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type><name>js/interactive_map.js</name>
             </action>
           </reference>
    ```

The test page is [here](http://www.weknowthegame.com/shop/testpage). Parts of it work, like clicking on the dots and they change color, but the form doesn't filter any data, and none of the images or descriptions show. It may be the html content but I can't be sure. I'm pretty much stuck right now and would love some help on getting this project rigged up.

Please help if you can, I'm really stumped.

This is the javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document

$j(document).ready(function() {
// begin Ready

    //...................................................
    // When the form changes
    $j('#mapForm').change(function() {

        var selectedContinent = $j('#mapForm option:selected').val();
        if (selectedContinent == 'ALL'){
            $j('a.dot').slideDown(1000);
        }else{
            $j('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $j('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        }

    });

    //...................................................
    // When a dot is clicked
    $j('a.dot').click(function(){

        $j('a.dot').removeClass('selected');
        $j(this).addClass('selected');

        var city = '.city_detail#' + $j(this).attr('city');
        var htmlCode = $j(city).html();

        $j('.detail_container').fadeOut(500, function(){
            $j('.detail_container .city_detail').html(htmlCode);
            $j('.detail_container').fadeIn(500);
        });

    });

// end Ready
});
```

This is the CSS

```
/*Interactive map*/
.map_container {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    background-image: url("../images/template/map.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 325px;
    width: 760px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.map_container a.dot {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: url("../images/template/dots.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
.map_container .form_continent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 265px;
}
.map_container .detail_container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 260px;
    width: 240px;
    left: 480px;
    top: 35px;
}
.map_container .city_detail {
    width: 230px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #A9B5C8;
    border-left-color: #A9B5C8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.map_container .clear_both {
    clear: both;
}
.map_container .city_photo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #424274;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #424274;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #424274;
}
.map_container .city_info {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.map_container .city_info h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.map_container .city_info h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3748;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.map_container .city_info p {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.city_detail_container {
    display: none;
}

.map_container a.dot:hover {
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}
.map_container a.dot.selected {
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}
```

And the html

```
    <div class="map_container"><a class="dot" style="left: 178px; top: 165px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="left: 240px; top: 73px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="left: 427px; top: 180px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="left: 412px; top: 94px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="left: 274px; top: 167px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 99px; left: 113px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 83px; left: 87px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 173px; left: 387px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 102px; left: 271px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 134px; left: 153px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 93px; left: 141px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 115px; left: 375px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 89px; left: 386px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 195px; left: 153px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 96px; left: 320px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 113px; left: 343px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 110px; left: 299px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 84px; left: 257px;"></a> <a class="dot" style="top: 76px; left: 273px;"></a> <form id="mapForm" class="form_continent" method="post"> <select id="continent" name="continent"> <option value="AF">Africa</option> <option value="AS">ASia</option> <option value="AU">Australia</option> <option value="EU">Europe</option> <option value="NA">North America</option> <option value="ME">Middle East</option> <option value="SA">South America</option> <option value="ALL">Show all continents</option> </select> </form> <!--City details     --->
<div class="detail_container">
<div class="city_detail">
<div class="city_info" style="width: 200px;">
<h3>Choose a city...</h3>
<p>Description goes here...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="city_detail_container"><!-- City -->
<div id="sydney" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src=".../images/cities/sydney.jpg" alt="sydney" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Sydney</h2>
<h3>Australia</h3>
<p>Pellentesque nibh felis, fddfdflitora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos commodo in interdum vitae leo.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="london" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/london.jpg" alt="sydney" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>London</h2>
<h3>Europe</h3>
<p>Curabitur fringilla. Nunc est ipsum, pretium quis, dapibus sed, varius non, lectus. Proin a quam. Praesent lacinia, eros quis aliquam porttitor, urna lacus volutpat urna, ut fermentum neque mi egestas dolor.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="riodejaneiro" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/riodejaneiro.jpg" alt="rio de janerio" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Rio de Janerio</h2>
<h3>South America</h3>
<p>Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="tokyo" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/tokyo.jpg" alt="brazil" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Tokyo</h2>
<h3>Asia</h3>
<p>Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla nam consectetuer. Lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="johannesburg" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/johannesburg.jpg" alt="johannesburg" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Johannesburg</h2>
<h3>Africa</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="johannesburg" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/johannesburg.jpg" alt="johannesburg" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Johannesburg</h2>
<h3>Africa</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="dallas" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/dallas.jpg" alt="dallas" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Dallas</h2>
<h3>North America</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="seattle" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/seattle.jpg" alt="seattle" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Seattle</h2>
<h3>North America</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="perth" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/perth.jpg" alt="perth" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Perth</h2>
<h3>Australia</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="tripoli" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/tripoli.jpg" alt="tripoli" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Tripoli</h2>
<h3>Africa</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="bogota" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/bogota.jpg" alt="bogota" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Bogot&aacute;</h2>
<h3>South America</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="newyorkcity" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/newyorkcity.jpg" alt="newyorkcity" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>New York City</h2>
<h3>North America</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="phnompenh" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/phnompenh.jpg" alt="phnompenh" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Phnom Penh</h2>
<h3>Asia</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper pharetra posuere.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="tianjin" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/tianjin.jpg" alt="tianjin" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Tianjin</h2>
<h3>Asia</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="puntaarenas" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/puntaarenas.jpg" alt="puntaarenas" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Punta Arenas</h2>
<h3>South America</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="buxoro" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/buxoro.jpg" alt="buxoro" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Buxoro</h2>
<h3>Middle East</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="anakapalle" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/anakapalle.jpg" alt="anakapalle" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Anakapalle</h2>
<h3>Middle East</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="albahr" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/albahr.jpg" alt="albahr" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Al Bahr</h2>
<h3>Middle East</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="rome" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/rome.jpg" alt="rome" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Rome</h2>
<h3>Europe</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- City -->
<div id="warszawa" class="city_detail"><img class="city_photo" src="images/cities/warszawa.jpg" alt="warszawa" width="75" height="75" />
<div class="city_info">
<h2>Warszawa</h2>
<h3>Europe</h3>
<p>Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide the path to `page.xml` where you added 2 `<action>` nodes?

Answer (score 0):

There is an javascript error on your test page.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">` is inside another `<script>` tag.

Try to move `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">` to after the closing tag (`</script>`) and see if it works.